# XML-Schema: how to set enumerations to one appearance per document

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to add a name-attribute to all my elements. To make sure that only some attribute values are allowed I created a restriction-pattern. Is there a way to make sure, that each enumeration value is used exactly once per document?

simpleStyle:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="myname">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

---

XML

```
<element  name="1"/>
<element  name="2"/>
<element  name="1"/>
```

The last one should not be allowed.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar concept called identity constraints, which may suit your purposes. You want to use `xs:unique`, which is a constraint on the parent element, not a property of an enumeration. Something like:

```
<xs:unique name="myconstraint">
 <xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>
 <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:unique>
```

The `selector` says which child elements the constraint applies to (all descendants in this example), and the `field` indicates which part must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly suggested by @xan and by [this guide](http://support.liquid-technologies.com/kb/a79/creating-a-unique-constrant-with-an-xsd.aspx), you could change your code this way:

1. **Define the `myname` enumeration**.
   This will allow only the usage of `1` or `2` values.

   ```
   <!-- The Enumeration definition (allowing only values 1 or 2) -->
   <xsd:simpleType name="myname">
       <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
           <xsd:enumeration value="1"/>
           <xsd:enumeration value="2"/>
       </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
   ```
2. **Define the `element` structure**.
   This will define the structure for the `<element name="..." />` node.

   ```
   <!-- the element definition (defines the <element /> structure) -->
   <xs:complexType name="elementType">
       <xs:attribute name="name" type="myname" use="required"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   ```
3. **Univque usage**.
   Define the `element` tag usage requiring an univoque usage of the `name` attribute.

   ```
   <xs:element name="myelements">

       <!-- The <element/> tag usage -->
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:element name="element" type="myname"/>
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>

       <!-- The univocity constraint -->
       <xs:unique name="nameUniqueConstraint">
           <xs:selector xpath="element"/>
           <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
       </xs:unique>

   </xs:element>
   ```

Please note that `nameUniqueConstraint` is just an arbitrary name to identify the constraint you want.